# Eviction before out of memory in Infinitispan

Tags: infinispan

When eviction is configured in infinitispan, it's necessary set maxEntries. But I'm not sure how many entries fit in the memory of the machine where infinitispan is executing.

Is possible to configure infinitispan to evict when memory is full?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is not (easily) possible yet. Here you can find tracking JIRA for this issue: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN-863

However this discussion is full of interesting ideas and maybe suitable workarounds for your case and it's definitely worth to look at: https://community.jboss.org/thread/165951?start=0&tstart=0

I'm afraid I can't give you anything more at this moment.
Hope that helps.